# Cannot create and run a JAR file from powershell

Tags: java, powershell, executable-jar

I have been unable to create an executable JAR file using the powershell. The error that keeps coming up is either "invalid header field" or "Could not find or load main class". I have successfully ran the code from Eclipse so I know it's not the code (I'm open for irony though). This is what my directory looks like:

...Documents/Java/drawingFX

inside drawingFX are the files "Drawing.java", "JIGraphicsUtility.java", and "Manifest.txt"

I now compile the .java file using the following command in powershell in the drawingFX directory where the files are:

```
PS C:\Users\colin\Documents\Java\drawingFX> javac --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\package\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml Drawing.java JIGraphicsUtility.java
```

the "module-path" part is to include some JAR files for the javafx package stuff. Now that I have compiled there are two more files in drawingFX: "Drawing.class" and "JIGraphicsUtility.class". Now I attempt to create the JAR file (I will mention that 'main' is located in Drawing.class") using the following command in powershell in the drawingFX directory:

```
PS C:\Users\colin\Documents\Java\drawingFX> jar cvfm run.jar Manifest.txt *.class
```

I get an "invalid header field" error. I will now include the code for all the files and then will include the directories of my CLASSPATH.

The following is the code for "Drawing.java":

```
/*
file:: Drawing.java
author:: Colin Rubow
last date modified:: 5/27/2020
description:: this program will play with the drawing javafx application
*/

package drawingFX;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Drawing extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start( Stage stage )
  {
    final int WIDTH = 700;
    final int HEIGHT = 400;

    GraphicsContext gc = JIGraphicsUtility.setUpGraphics( stage, "Drawing", WIDTH, HEIGHT );

    gc.strokeLine( 100, 125, 100, 300 );
    gc.setStroke( Color.RED );
    gc.setLineWidth( 5 );
    gc.strokeLine( 300, 75, 550, 75);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int red = rand.nextInt( 0xFF );
    int green = rand.nextInt ( 0xFF );
    int blue = rand.nextInt ( 0xff );
    Color randomColor = Color.rgb( red, green, blue );
    gc.setStroke( randomColor );

    gc.strokeLine( 0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1 );
  }

  public static void main( String [] args )
  {
    launch( args );
  }
}
```

The following code is from the "JIGraphicsUtility.java":

```
/*

*/

package drawingFX;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JIGraphicsUtility
{
  public static GraphicsContext setUpGraphics( Stage stage, String title, int height, int width )
  {
    stage.setTitle( title );
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas( height, width );
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D( );
    Group root = new Group( canvas );
    stage.setScene( new Scene( root ) );
    stage.show( );
    return gc;
  }
}
```

The following is from the "Manifest.txt":

```
Main-Class: drawingFX.Drawing
```

The following are what is in CLASSPATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\package\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib
C:\Users\colin\Documents\Java\drawingFX
C:\Users\colin\Documents\Java
```

I believe the current "invalid header field" error is due to the Manifest.txt file but I do not know. As for the "Could not find or load main class" error I have no idea as I have tried many things.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `Drawing` class is in package `drawingFX`, so the value for `Main-Class` in your manifest should be `drawingFX.Drawing`

Comment: I have made the change but error "invalid header field" is still the response. I'll change the post to reflect the change.

Comment: Can you double-check the `jar` command that you're running? The order of the parameters matters ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27539275)) although the command in your question looks good. I tried it on my end and didn't see any errors.

Comment: @roadkill I have double checked the [jar] command and the order is correct. Does your [CLASSPATH] point to anything significant that mine doesn't?